# Automatically escaping HTML with Hiccup, is it possible?

Tags: clojure, hiccup

I just tried this with Hiccup:

```
(hiccup.core/html [:h1 "<script>alert('xss');</script>"])
```

and to my surprise I got an alert box, Hiccup is not escaping strings by default. I see that there's a method to escape strings, but in my opinion if it's not the default, sooner or later you'll forget and be vulnerable to XSS.

Is there a way in Hiccup to have it escape strings by default?

Comment: HTH: https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/issues/5

Answer (score 4):

hiccup `2.0.0-alpha1` has escaping by default. You just need to change the `hiccup.core/html` call to `hiccup2.core/html` and it should work without any change.

```clj
(str (hiccup2.core/html [:h1 "<script>alert('xss');</script>"]))
```

I've upgraded my project from 1.0.5 and it's working without any regression.

Answer (score 2):

No, but [`core/h` is an alias for `escape-html`](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/31c06bec7eec038c6d3bfc051f4033362f142ffb/src/hiccup/core.clj#L16) that makes it slightly more convenient:

```
(hiccup.core/html [:h1 (hiccup.core/h "<script>alert('xss');</script>")])
```